# Declination of Jahre(n)

Tags: grammatical-case

"Many nouns get an -n ending in the plural, for example "die Affen", "die Studenten" and "die Russen". In most cases the -n ending applies in the nominative, accusative and dative, but some nouns only receive the -n ending in the dative, for example "die Jahre(n)". Why is this?

Comment: @Steve It is _die Jahre_, but the dative is _den Jahren_.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that _"Why is this?" or Why does Jahre only have the -en ending in dative plural, and -e in the other plural cases?_ is the main question?

Comment: As Takkat wrote, a complete list might get too long, but maybe [this overview on noun paradigms](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexionsparadigma#Substantivparadigmen) helps you for a systematic approach.It lists _Topf_ and _Monat_ as further examples.

Comment: To Marzipanherz. Why does Jahre only have the -en ending in dative plural, and -e in the other plural cases? is the main question.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Nice overview, but is it complete? For instance, the following does not fit: _das/dem Datum_ -> _des Datum**s**_ -> _die/der Dat**en**_

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I guess, this the linked overview omits nouns with a "recent" import from other languages.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich It is not complete (compare. e.g.: _Herz, Hobel_), yet a common (not detailed) way to denote the declension classes of German that cover the vast majority of the vocabulary. However, if done properly, one would denote the genitive _-es_ in the various classes as _-(e)s_. With that, you would also see that _Datum_ belongs to what Wikipedia refers to as "class 2" (masculines/neuters, mixed declension).

Comment: To help to answer your question please help us to know why you expect regularity, and why do you expect an explanation to irregularity in declension. (Is there a rule without exception?).

Answer (score 7):

German nouns can be roughly divided into:

*Weak* nouns with plural and genitive ending with -en, example: Der Hase, plural *die Hasen*, genitive *des Hasen*.

*Strong* nouns with other nominative plural endings (such as -e or -er, sometimes with umlaut) and a genitive usually ending with -es or -s, example: Der Tag, plural *die Tage*, genitive *des Tages*.

There are also mixed cases, for example das Herz, plural *die Herzen*, but genitive *des Herzens*.

In all cases the dative plural ends with -en (or -n).

These forms have their origin in the declension classes of Old High German which originate in Germanic declension classes which in turn originate in Indo-European classes. The strong declension emerged out of vocalic declensions and the weak declension emerged out of the consonantic declension which in turn have their origin in the Indo-European thematic and athematic stems.

A good German dictionary contains the genitive and plural ending of each noun, which is generally sufficient to derive all forms.

A list of all weak or strong nouns would be very large and of little practical value, so I would advise to consult a dictionary and look at the genitive and plural endings supplied.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't explan why "die Jahre" becomes "den Jahren" in the dative, which is what I am asking.

Comment: All noun classes end with -en or -n in the dative plural. I added this information. The other cases have different endings, the reason for which I tried to explain in the answer.

Comment: It does explain that, by pointing out to you that this comes with the declension type of _Jahr_ (which needs to be learned). (About 90% of masculine one-syllable nouns in German are of the _Jahr_ declension type.)

Comment: Could you add an example of a vocalic and a consonantic declension, and possibly also Indoeuropean thematic and athematic stems?